# Changing the order of integration - still getting non-integrable function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_0^4 \int_{\sqrt y}^2 \sqrt{x^3 + 1} \, dx \, dy$$

I am supposed to change the order of integration to evaluate. I was thinking to simply switch the order of both the integrals and the $dx$/$dy$.

When I do this, however, I get an equally non-integrable function (the original times $4$)

Am I supposed to also be changing the bounds of the integrals in addition to switching the order?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try [sketching the region of integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+the+region+0%3Cy%3C4+and+sqrt%28y%29%3Cx%3C2). It's bounded between the horizontal lines $y=0$ and $y=4$ and between the half-parabola $x=\sqrt y$ and vertical line $x=2$. Notice how $x$ depends on $y$. Swapping the integration order will require the opposite, describing $y$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Repeating the other comments:  **Draw a picture** of the region of integration.  That will help you determine what the interchanged integral is.